# How to map fetched Google cloud datastore Entity (com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity) to Custom Java object

Tags: java, spring, mapping, google-cloud-datastore

I'm fetching a list of Datastore Entity (com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity) using below query (com.google.cloud.datastore.Query). I'm unable to map the Datastore Entity object to my custom Java object. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
                .setNamespace("abc")
                .setKind("ca")
                .setFilter(StructuredQuery.PropertyFilter.eq("name", "xyz"))
                .build();

QueryResults<Entity> tasks = datastore.run(query);

for (QueryResults<Entity> it = tasks; it.hasNext(); ) {
            Entity entity = it.next();
            User user = entity.toUser();//How to map to my custom Java class
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is relation between `User` and entity in Datastore, and what exactly you want to do, however there is `getPropertyMap` method ([reference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-datastore/latest/index.html)) in the Datastore Java API. The method seems to be ideal for you task as it returns `Map<String,Value>`.

All you need to do is to implement new constructor in `User` class that will create `User` instance from this `Map`.

Than the line should look like this:
`User user = new User(entity.getPropertyMap());`

I am sure this is just one of tones of ways to do it :)

I hope it will help!